# avoid mongo driver changes dates on a query using builders

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have some problems querying, on a net web service, documents from a mongo db (version 3.4.4)

It seems the dates are converted To UniversalTime, I would like avoid that conversion.

For example with this code i want search for documents with date 9 july 2018

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new    MongoClient("mongodb://xxx");
IMongoDatabase database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("mydb");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("mycollection");

DateTime dateFrom = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-09");
DateTime dateTo = DateTime.Parse("2018-07-10");

var query_filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.And
(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Gte("utcData", new BsonDateTime(dateFrom)) &
                         Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Lte("utcData", new BsonDateTime(dateTo))
                     );

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(query_filter.Render(collection.DocumentSerializer,
                          collection.Settings.SerializerRegistry).ToString());
```

but this is the query sent to the server

```
{ "utcData" : { "$gte" : ISODate("2018-07-08T22:00:00Z"), "$lte" : ISODate("2018-07-09T22:00:00Z") } }
```

Why is one day subtracted from dates? Is there a way to avoid any changes on dates?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this one create utc date:

```
DateTime.Parse("2018-07-09", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture , System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
```